# anonymize using tor while using owasp zap

Tags: proxy, tor

I am using OWASP zap using proxy `127.0.0.1:8080` but sites can see me.
I want to use tor.
request should go like browser -> zap -> tor -> web

I tried with `proxychains`

- using `strixt_chain`
- added tor and zap proxy

  ```
  sock5 127.0.0.1 9050
  http  127.0.0.1 8080
  ```

but it is giving connection timeout

Answer (score 0):

for me it works the following way:

- launch tor browser
- run `netstat -tulpen | grep tor` to figure out, which port is used (for me 9150)
- configure proxychains to use tor with `strixt_chain`: `socks5 127.0.0.1 9150` (do not miss the second "s" in "socks" and use the port-number you figured out before)
- run zap with proxychains: `proxychains /path/to/zap.sh`
- configure your browser to use the local zap proxy `127.0.0.1:8080` (or whatever port you have configured in zap. do NOT configure zap to use an external proxy itsself, proxychain will do this for you)
- check https://check.torproject.org/